# python parsing string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to parse a string from this:

```
CN=ERT234,OU=Computers,OU=ES1-HER,OU=ES1-Seura,OU=RES-ES1,DC=resu,DC=kt,DC=elt
```

To this:

```
ES1-HER / ES1-Seura
```

Any easy way to do this with regex?

Comment: At least try to solve the problem yourself first, this is not a resource that magically generates code for badly described problems.

Comment: Why are you regexing LDAP strings? There's python modules that will parse that for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answers. I use a different python version embedded in a external program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re    
>>> s = 'CN=ERT234,OU=Computers,OU=ES1-HER,OU=ES1-Seura,OU=RES-ES1,DC=resu,DC=kt,DC=elt'
>>> re.findall('OU=([^,]+)', s)
['Computers', 'ES1-HER', 'ES1-Seura', 'RES-ES1']
>>> re.findall('OU=([^,]+)', s)[1:3]
['ES1-HER', 'ES1-Seura']
>>> ' / '.join(re.findall('OU=([^,]+)', s)[1:3])
'ES1-HER / ES1-Seura'
```

Don't use `str` as a variable name. It shadows builtin function [`str`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str).